# Getting ACL_ENTRY_ERROR after acl_create_entry on Linux

Tags: linux, acl

I'm writing a program that sets acl permissions for a given user/group. Very similar to the "setfacl" command.
According to a given user/group I search first if the entry already exists. If I get a NULL then I call acl_create_entry. When I check the ACL via acl_check, I get an ACL_ENTRY_ERROR.
The function is something similar to this:

```
/*ar_pobj=Path or file name, ar_tagType=ACL_USER or ACL_GROUP, ar_ptagQual=User name or group name, ar_pperms=string with permissions "rwx-"*/
int addPermissions(char *ar_pobj, acl_tag_t ar_tagType, char *ar_ptagQual, char *ar_pperms)
{
    acl_t la_acl;
    id_t la_qual;
    acl_entry_t la_entry;
    int la_error;

    la_acl=acl_get_file(par_obj,ACL_TYPE_ACCESS);
    if (la_acl == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    switch(ar_tagType)
    {
    case ACL_USER:
        la_qual=userIdFromName(ar_ptagQual);/*This function works fine*/
        if(-1==la_qual)
        {
            acl_free(la_acl);                
            return -1;
        }
        break;
    case ACL_GROUP:
        la_qual=groupIdFromName(ar_ptagQual);/*This function works fine*/
        if(-1==la_qual)
        {
            acl_free(la_acl);
            return -1;
        }
        break;
    default:
        acl_free(la_acl);
        return -1;
    }
    la_entry = findEntry(la_acl,ar_tagType,la_qual);/*This function returns NULL as the entry was not found*/

    if(NULL==la_entry)
    {
        if (acl_create_entry(&la_acl, &la_entry) == -1)/*Returns OK*/
        {
            acl_free(la_acl);
            return -1;
        }
        la_error=acl_check(la_acl,NULL);/*HERE IS WHERW I GET THE ERROR*/
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Any clues? Thank you in advance.
**edit** This error always happens if you did not set the tag type and qualifier. But I am still getting it after doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Issue solved! The problem was that I forgot to recalculate the ACL mask. Calling acl_calc_mask(&la_acl) right before calling acl_set_file solved the problem.